# Equation solution using minimization

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I have an equation `F[x,y]=0`. I need to plot `y` as a function of `x`. Due to the properties of the function `F[x,y]`, it is impossible to just use `ContourPlot` for this problem. Also, `FindRoot` (I don't know why) doesn't work in this situation.

However, `NMinimize[...,Method -> "NelderMead"]` works well. I need to find all `y[i]` for every `x[i]` starting from some point `{x[0], y[0]}` which I know a priori. I can do it step by step by hand and it takes a lot of time, but due to my low knowledge in Mathematica to date I can't automotize this process.

So, please, could anyone help me to to write such a code in Mathematica:

1. put starting point `{x[0], y[0]`.
2. for i from 1 to N

   do

   `x[i]=x[i-1] + dx`,

   `NMinimize[{F[x[i], y[i]], y[i-1]-dy < y[i] < y[i-1] + dy}, {y[i]}, Method -> "NelderMead"]`

   (*so, for every `x[i]` we find `y[i]` and look for `y[i+1]` in the vicinity of `y[i]`;
   `dx` is just a step, `dy` is a small constant (much less then `y[i]`*)
3. Plot the points `{x[i], y[i]}`.

For example, two steps of this algorithm:

`{x[0], y[0]} = {0, 0}`

`x[1] = 0 + 0.05`

`NMinimize[{F[x[1], y[1]], 0 - 0.1 < y[1] < 0 + 0.1}, {y[1]}, Method -> "NelderMead"]`

we get `y[1] = 0.05`.

`x[2] = 0.05 + 0.05`

`NMinimize[{F[x[2], y[2]], 0.05 - 0.1 < y[2] < 0.05 + 0.1}, {y[2]}, Method -> "NelderMead"]`

we get `y[2] = 0.75`.

...

Here is a link for a function I am interested in https://yadi.sk/d/r9wI4iobgkjNB

Comment: I submitted an edit of this post, making everything conform to Mathematica syntax, rather than the mix of LaTeX and Mathematica that was before. Also some syntax errors got corrected along the way. Hopefully this can offer some insight on top of the answer I suggested.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what properties of the function make it impossible to use `ContourPlot`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "`F[x,y]=0`". Your `F[x, t, a, b]` does not seem to equal zero for `a = 100`, `b = 1/10`.  Your code outline suggests you're trying to follow the bottom of the trough: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3NCAD.png) Does that look right?

Comment: Same question also appears on Wolfram Community [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/500576?p_p_auth=9B8zwjNd) (You really should mention and link when a question is cross-posted). The function is difficult to evaluate in certain ranges, which is almost certainly why `FindRoot` apparently has problems with it.

Comment: I am sorry for a long delay.

Comment: I am sorry for a long delay. Rahul, I am not sure, but I think that ContourPlot doesn't work here because my function is complex and has singularities. Also, I have an idea about solutions when a and b have certain values (for some physical reasons) and the solution that ContourPlot gives doesn't match with these solutions.

Comment: Michael E2, I am sorry, but I am not sure that this picture is right. When a=100 and b=0.1 the solutions (two curves) should look like the solution in this file https://yadi.sk/d/RNJhkcOsgp3XR, and when a=0.1 and b=100 like here (one solution) https://yadi.sk/d/xgjF_B1bgp3hK

Comment: Dear Daniel, I am sorry that I havn't mentioned it. I promice I will do it next time. The thing is that I've been trying to build these solutions for more than 2 months (without results), that's why I write this question on several forums (this one, WC and one Russian forum).  LLlAMnYP (see below) have written such a code I asked about, so now I'm trying to use it. However, as I've already found out "by hands", NMinimize (Nelder Mead minimization) also doesn't work very well (as it was promised by aughtors of some articles). It finds "extra" unphysical minimums (as it looks for local mins)

Comment: @Artem, Here are the 3D plots of the function `F` as defined in the linked file in your question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9nMia.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/3OaIc.png. In both cases, `F` does not seem to equal zero.  In the second case `1/F[x, y, 100, 1/10]` seems to have a zero curve that resembles the one in the file linked in your recent comment.  Could that be what you want?  (But `F` vs. its reciprocal seems an unlikely mistake.)

Comment: Michael E2, thank you for your response. No, it is not what I need. What I need is to solve F[x,y]=0.

Comment: (@Artem, if you put an @ in front of my name, I will be notified when you respond.) All the numerical evidence I've seen so far, including plots, indicates `F[x,y]=0` has no solutions though.

Comment: @Michael E2, thank you for your comment. I see what you mean, but I have already checked this equation so many times, so I am sure that it is right. However, I will certainly check it once again.

Answer (score 1):

I add the following code to the end of your notebook:

```
Clear[x];
dx = 0.05;
{x[0], y[0]} = 
     {0, y /. Last@NMinimize[{F[0, y, a, b]}, {y},
              Method -> "NelderMead"]}; (* this line determines the starting point *)
Do[{x[i], y[i]} = 
    {i*dx, y /. Last@
                NMinimize[{F[i*dx, y, a, b], 
                           y[i - 1] - dx < y < y[i - 1] + dx},
                           {y}, Method -> "NelderMead"]}, {i, 10}]
Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, 10}];
ListPlot@%
```

In order to achieve what seems to have been requested. Appropriate adjustment of starting conditions (`dx`, constraint for `y` and so on) is necessary depending on desired results.

[image: result]

Choosing a different starting point is as easy as `{x[0], y[0]} = {0, 3}`. The boundaries on `x` are defined simply by the points at which you choose to evaluate `NMinimize`. I did `Do[...i*dx,..., {i, 10}]`, but you can just as well do it further, say, up to {i, 100} which will give you points for all x up to 5.

Defining boundaries for `y` is passing extra constraints to `NMinimize` (you should check the documentation for this function).

Here's some code.

```
Clear[x, y];
dx = 0.05;
{x[0], y[0]} = {0, 3};
Do[{x[i], y[i]} = {i*dx, 
   y /. Last@
     NMinimize[{F[i*dx, y, a, b], 0 < y < 4, 
       y[i - 1] - dx < y < y[i - 1] + dx}, {y}, 
      Method -> "NelderMead"]}, {i, 100}]
Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, 100}];
ListPlot@%
```

Comment: Dear LLlAMnYP, thank you for your help. But could you explain why it desn't work (on my computer)                                                              F1[x_, y_, a_, b_] := Abs[x - y*Sqrt[(y^2 - 9)/(2 y^2 - 9)]] + a + b;
a = 0;
b = 0;
Clear[x];
dx = 0.05;
{x[0], y[0]} = {0, 
   y /. Last@NMinimize[{F[0, y, a, b]}, {y}, Method -> "NelderMead"]};
Do[{x[i], y[i]} = {i*dx, 
   y /. Last@
     NMinimize[{F[i*dx, y, a, b], 
       y[i - 1] - dx < y < y[i - 1] + dx}, {y}, 
      Method -> "NelderMead"]}, {i, 10}]
Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, 10}];
ListPlot@%

Comment: Also, for me it would be interesting to consider {x,0,5}, {y,0,4}.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I've just opened your linked notebook, run the cells there, then copied my answer to the bottom of it and run the commands from that and it returned to me the plot I provided in my answer.

Comment: Dear LLlAMnYP, I am sorry for a delay. I have checked it again and now this program works. Thanks!

Comment: Dear LLlAMnYP, could you tell me how to make constraints {x,0,5},{y,0,4} for this code and how to chose other starting point (for example x=0 and y=3) ? https://yadi.sk/d/dcllKEyegp4u8

Comment: Not until Tuesday, I'm afraid. We've got a long weekend in Germany :-)

Comment: It's ok)) Thank you!

Comment: Also, LLlAMnYP, is it possible to minimize not F[x,y] for every x[i], but F[x'+I*x'',y] for every x'[i], where I is the imaginary unit ?

Comment: could you tell me how to make constraints {x,0,5},{y,0,4} for this code and how to chose other starting point (for example x=0 and y=3) ? Also, is it possible to minimize not F[x,y] for every x[i], but F[x'+I*x'',y] for every x'[i], where I is the imaginary unit ?

Comment: @Artem Done. I'm not quite sure about your last question. My code minimizes the function `F[i*dx, y, a, b]` assuming fixed `i*dx`, `a`, and `b` with respect to `y`. Then it goes to the next value of `i*dx` and does the same again. You're welcome to change the first argument of `F` to whatever you like. For example `F[3i*dx+0.1 I*i, y, a, b]` or any other expression. Just be aware, that `NMinimize` minimizes real numbers. If the function will be complex-valued, you'll need to handle this somehow, by, perhaps, taking the absolute value of it.

Comment: I am sorry, my question was inaccurate. So, 1. is it possible to cosider only {x,0,5},{y,0,4} and how to do it? 2. How to choose other starting point for minimization?  3. It is possible to minimize Abs[F[x+I*x',y]], i.e. to find x' and y for every x[i] if {x,0,5},{y,0,4},{x',0,5} and then plot the dependence of y on x and y on x' ?

Comment: Did you read the update to my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't read it before you noticed it because I just did not expect to find some updates above and waited for them below ))